# Is there any way to improve (shorten) this F# code?

Tags: parsing, f#

I have a very good grasp of the syntax and features of F# as well as some of the concepts that mesh well with the language. However, I do not have enough experience writing it to feel comfortable that the way I am handling the language is appropriate.

Ignoring the fact that I do not provide proper escaping functionality for the file format, is there any way I could write this code better? I know that this is a trivial example, but I fear that I might be making things too hard on myself with this code.

Also, is there a way that I could write this more robustly so that adding in an escape sequence for the ";" character would be easier?

```
module Comments

open System.IO

type Comment = { Author: string; Body: string }

let parseComment (line:string) =
    match line.Split(';') with
    | [|author; body|] -> Some({Author=author; Body=body})
    | _                -> None

let filterOutNone maybe = match maybe with | Some(_) -> true | _ -> false
let makeSome some = match some with | Some(v) -> v | _ -> failwith "error"

let readAllComments () = 
    File.ReadAllLines("comments.txt")
    |> Array.map parseComment
    |> Array.filter filterOutNone
    |> Array.map makeSome
```

Comment: I don't know F#, but does it not have mapMaybe like haskell does? And what about list comprehensions for all those maps and filters?

Comment: Would help if the question described the problem that the code is intended to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into [`Array.choose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370619.aspx). Using that function cuts the length of your code in half, because you have basically reinvented it. (I did the same at some point ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I would upvote your answer if I had the privileges to do so on this site.

Answer (score 7):

Most of your code can be replaced with a comprehension:

```
type Comment = { Author: string; Body: string }

let readAllComments () = 
  [|for line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("comments.txt") do
      match line.Split ';' with
      | [|author; body|] -> yield {Author=author; Body=body}
      | _ -> ()|]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `makeSome` function is confusingly named. The word "make" suggests that it will create a `Some`, but what it actually does is take a `Some` and then return its value. So it should be called something like `getValueFromSome` or `getValueFromOption`. However none of that matters since it's just a reimplementation of the built-in `Option.get` function, so you should use that.

That being said you actually don't need this function at all if you use `Array.choose` as wmeyer suggests (which you should). Still if you ever do need this function in a  different context, you should use `Option.get` rather than reimplementing it yourself.